# getting the id from a row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable that shows the result from a database

```
for(VoertuigenModel m : vModel.selectVoertuigen())
        {   
            if(m.getStatus().equals("Beschikbaar"))
            {
                tableModelVoertuigen.addRow(new Object[]{
                        m.getMerk(),
                        m.getType(),
                        m.getKleur(),
                        m.getStatus(),
                        m.getId()
                });
            }
        }
```

And this looks like this

[image: Jtable example]

Now  How can I get the AUTO-ID when from a row that is selected?

For example I want to select the 3rd row then I want to set '4' in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now How can I get the AUTO-ID when from a row that is selected?

- Add `ListSelectionListener` to `JTable` `SelectionModel()` using `addListSelectionListener`
- On Selection event, get the selected row index of the table view using `table.getSelectedRow()`. Selection data actually describes selected cells in the `"view"` (table data as it appears after any sorting or filtering) rather than in the table model. while sorting, filtering, or user manipulation of columns, you must convert selection coordinates using the `JTable`'s  conversion methods:

  1. `convertRowIndexToModel(row)`: maps the row index of view to underlying `TableModel`
  2. `convertColumnIndexToModel(column)`: maps the column index of view to underlying `TableModel`
- Get the column Index by invoking `getColumnIndex("AUTO-ID")` on `JTable`'s column model

  ```
   table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

          @Override
          public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

              int row =  table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
              int col = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("AUTO-ID");

              int auto_id = (Integer) table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
                   // assuming that `m.getId()` is returning `int` 
                  //while adding with addRow() function
          }
      });
  ```

**Note:**: use **[`int[] getSelectedRows()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29)** function of `JTable` when you are selecting more then one row and want to work with them.

Comment: I want the ID as a INTEGER not as a STRING and I am selecting only 1 row at the time

Comment: How would i know whither you have added it as string! :) *updated the answer*. If you are using Integer as the object type of AUTO-ID then you can replace String with Integer in the above code. Or use Integer.parseInt(string) function to convert the auto_id field to integer.